# Laravel ManyToMany relationship Is reversing tables names

Tags: laravel, laravel-models

i need to make the post accepts as many language as i need so i have tow models `post` and  `language`
in post model:

```
public function languages(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Language::class);
}
```

in my language model :

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Post::class);
}
```

post migration :

```
  Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->boolean('puplished')->default(false);
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

language migration :

```
Schema::create('languages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('text')->unique();
        $table->string('value');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

i also created post_language_table migration to connect post and language:

```
Schema::create('post_language', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('language_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

in my controller :

```
$langs = collect(json_decode($request->languages,true))->pluck('id');
    $post = [];
    $post['body'] = $request->body;
    $post['title'] = $request->title;
    $post['user_id'] = 1;
    $new_post = \App\Models\Post::create($post);
    $new_post->languages()->attach($langs);
```

but when i try to insert new record to tha database this error shows:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.language_post' doesn't exist (SQL: 
insert into `language_post` (`language_id`, `post_id`) values (1, 4), (3, 4), (4, 4))
```

**so the problem is that for some reason the table name is exchanged !**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Laravel convention for pivot tables based on models is `table1_table2`, where `table1` is the lowercase, singular version of the model that comes first in the alphabet, and `table2` is the lowercase, singular version of the model that comes last in the alphabet. So in your case, the `pivot` table should be `language_post`, since L comes before P.

You can modify the pivot table in your migration:

```
Schema::create('language_post', ...)
```

Or override it on the relationship:

`Post.php`:

```
public function languages() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(Language::class, 'post_language');
}
```

`Language.php`

```
public function posts() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_language');
}
```

The 2nd param passed to `belongsToMany` is the name of the pivot table.

From the documentation:

> To determine the table name of the relationship's intermediate table, Eloquent will join the two related model names in alphabetical order.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: just what i needed !